# Is this page coded incorrectly for proper HTML?

Tags: html, xhtml

Learning a bit about the differences between XHTML and HTML, I looked at the source of one of our pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Is this correct? Seems like it’s trying to be a HTML page, but then has a link to an XHTML namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like somebody was using an XHTML doctype, and the associated `xmlns` attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

And then they heard HTML5 was the shiny new doctype, so they changed to that and ended up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

Just to make it clear, this is what it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Comment: Which means you can drop the `xmlns` attribute because it's not required by HTML5.

Comment: @James Allardice It _is_ required for XHTML5, however.

Comment: @mc10 - Indeed it is, but as the answer is talking about HTML5, that attribute is not needed (as the answer has now been updated to show).

Answer (score 1):

Your code provided,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

is perfectly fine. It means that the web page is using [XHTML5](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-xml-xhtml-5/), an XML serialization of HTML5. If you would like your pages to be rendered as proper XHTML5, though, the content-type header of the page should be sent as `application/xhtml+xml`; `text/html` is not allowed in XHTML5.

For practical reasons (especially compatibility with previous IE versions, most notably IE 6), you should use HTML5, not XHTML5, like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Note, of course, that the `xmlns` attribute has been removed.